# Is it possible to store additional information to spinner items?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I create a dropdown using a spinner and an ArrayAdapter. Now I want to save additional information to a spinner item. 
I would like to add an integer for the id to these items. This id should not be shown in the dropdown, but when I call `spinner.getSelectedItem()`, I would like to have the possibility to do something like `int id = spinner.getSelectedItem().getExtraInteger();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Dog {
   int age;
   public Dog(int age) {this.age = age;}
   @override String toString() { return "TextToDisplayInAdapter"; }
   public int customInt() { return age; }
}
```

then in your Activity/Fragment/Whatever

```
ArrayAdapter<Dog> adapter = 
new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, dogs);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

// somewhere else
Dog dog = (Dog) spinner.getSelectedItem();
dog.customInt();
```